# Login script using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm implementing a login script which isn't working correctly. I want users to be able to login with either their usernames or emails. I have two tables:

**user** - contains login information(username, password, email, isactive)

**userprofile** - contains profile information

**ISSUES/ERRORS**:

1. Logging in with the email addresses doesn't work.
2. If the username alone is entered, leaving the password field empty, the user is still logged in regardless.

**THE CODE**(isactive checks if a user's account has been activated after email verification)

```
    $uname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
    $isActive = 1;
    $getId = 0;
        try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username OR email = :email AND password = :password AND isactive = :isactive");
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $uname, ':email' => $uname, ':password' => $pword, ':isactive' => $isActive));
    $numrows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    //to enable me count number of rows returned
    $number = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);


    $_SESSION['username'] = $numrows['username'];
    $getId = $numrows['Id'];//get the id of the user

    }catch(PDOException $ex){
    echo 'QUERY ERROR: ' . $ex->getMessage();
      }


    /*this checks to see that the user has a profile (userId is a foreign key, thus  user.Id = userprofile.userId always)*/
     try{
       $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * from userprofile WHERE userId = :userId");
       $query->execute(array(':userId' => $getId));
       $row = $query->fetchAll();

       }catch(PDOException $exc){
    echo 'QUERY ERROR: ' . $exc->getMessage();
     }

       //Check results and log user in
        if(count($number) == 1 && count($row) == 1){

        header("Location: index.php");
    }
        else {$errorMessage = "<p style='color:#ff851b'>Invalid username or password</p>";}
```

What do i need to modify to get this working? Thanks

Comment: We're not a crowdsourced debugging service. At least narrow down the problem to a specific line that you can form a specific technical question about. Don't just dump a page full of code with the vaguest error description and expect us to debug it for you.

Comment: To correct the second issue, test if the password and the username are given. If not, return an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily include the row count in your query as well:

And adjust the query :

```
SELECT *, count(*) AS numrows 
FROM user 
WHERE (username = :username OR email = :email) AND 
       password = :password AND isactive = :isactive
```

Please make the following changes:

```
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $uname, 
                     ':email' => $uname, 
                     ':password' => $pword, 
                     ':isactive' => $isActive));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(!$row){
   throw new Exception('User not found');
}

//get user data
$numrows = (int)$row['numrows'];
if($numrows === 1){
    //found a user
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
    $id = $row['Id'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this is good. But the syntax in the select statement gave some errors. Had to use this one..`SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = :username OR email = :email) AND password = :password AND isactive = :isactive`. I think using count(*) is the easiest way to count returned rows in PDO. Though if there were a function such as mysql_num_rows, it'll be much better.

Comment: Well there is PDO::rowCount, the problem is it sometimes does not work right with SELECT, its more for affected row like UPDATE/DELTE/INSERT

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is this one; some brackets are needed:

Before:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username OR email = :email AND password = :password AND isactive = :isactive");
```

After:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE ((username = :username AND password = :password) OR (email = :email AND password = :password)) AND isactive = :isactive");
```

---

Also, in this line you are assigning `$uname` to `username` *and* `email` - possible copy/paste error here as well?

```
$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $uname, ':email' => $uname, ':password' => $pword, ':isactive' => $isActive));
```

Comment: Thanks. It's just one field, which could take either username or an email that's why `$uname` is assigned to both

Comment: yes i think so but I now get the error "undefined parameter number" after modifying the query. is it wrong to obtain number of rows returned like this: `$number = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`.?

Comment: I'm not able to test at the moment, but from memory you could give this a try: `$stmt->execute(...); $num = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM); $number = $num[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = :username OR email = :email) AND password = :password AND isactive = :isactive"
```

as query... Should work...

Comment: ok thanks. I get the error "undefined parameter number" after adjusting the query. is it wrong to obtain number of rows like this:            `$number = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);`.